# Choosing an overloaded function based on a condition

Tags: java, groovy

I have an overloaded method in Groovy that I call depending on a condition:

```
Boolean isUnix = getIsUnix()
Map result
if (isUnix) {
  result = TestAbstract.execute(className, "JAVA_OPTS=/dev/urandom")
} else {
  result = TestAbstract.execute(className)
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result? Something like:

```
TestAbstract.execute(className, isUnix ? "additionalParam" : )
```

Note that I do **not** want the following:

```
TestAbstract.execute(className, isUnix ? "additionalParam" : "") //this is bad
```

Because that overrides the possible default value of the string. I want to conditionally call two overloaded variants of one method:

If true, call the first variant of the method and pass parameters `A` and `B`; else, call the second variant of the method and pass parameter `A` only.

Is there a more concise solution?

Comment: The compiler can't do that since it doesn't know whether `isUnix` will be true or false. But why don't you just do `Map<?,?> result = isUnix ? TestAbstract.execute(className, "JAVA_OPTS=/dev/urandom") : TestAbstract.execute(className);` if you want something other than your solution? Besides the fact that the map is declared outside the if block I see nothing bad with your first snippet.

Comment: @Thomas You are correct that that is one solution. If you change comment -> answer, I'll give you an upvote :) I just wanted something more concise, but it seems that this is the most readable way to do it.

Comment: thx, but it's fine for me to leave it as a comment. The other answers are more interesting anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`GroovyObject.invokeMethod(methodName, args)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.12/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObject.html#invokeMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) meta-programming approach if you like playing around with dynamic and meta Groovy features. It allows you to define a single place where you invoke a method and define a list of parameters beforehand. Consider following example:

```
class TestAbstract {
    static void execute(String className, String params = "defaults") {
        println "Executing with className = '${className}' and params = '${params}'"
    }
}

def runTest(boolean isUnix) {
    def params = ['MyClassName']

    if (isUnix) {
        params << 'additionalParam'
    }

    TestAbstract.invokeMethod('execute', params as Object[])
}

runTest(true)
runTest(false)
```

In this example `TestAbstract.execute(className, params)` uses default value for a second method parameter. `GroovyObject.invokeMethod(className, args)` expects second parameter to be an array of parameters, so we can pass single element array or two elements array if needed.

Running this example produces following output:

```
Executing with className = 'MyClassName' and params = 'additionalParam'
Executing with className = 'MyClassName' and params = 'defaults'
```

Even though you can do it in a meta/dynamic way I would say that:

```
isUnix ? TestAbstract.execute(className, additionalParam) : TestAbstract.execute(className)
```

looks more readable to me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I agree about the readability, but will check out meta-programming for sure!

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
Consumer<String> classNameConsumer = isUnix 
    ? cn -> TestAbstract.execute(cn, "JAVA_OPTS=/dev/urandom")
    : cn -> TestAbstract.execute(cn);
classNameConsumer.accept(className);
```

Whether that's a "better" way is up to taste I guess.

Since `isUnix` is not going to change during runtime, I'd say it's safe to create the consumer as a static final class member which should improve readability.